# PHP: inserting the output of a function into a string

Tags: php, function

I'm writing a custom PHP function to make it easier to generate CSS styles that use media queries.

My function was getting quite repetitive, so I created a second function, that I placed inside the first function. The second function contained all the repetitive code.

The second function produces a string of text, which is inserted inside another string from the first function.

However, I find the final output places the second function text string ***outside*** of the first function string. How can I correct this?

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
function css_bgcolor_height_embded($region, $height_value, $mobile_setting, $mobile_custom_height)
{
    function css_height_output($region, $height_value, $class_prefix, $height_division)
    {
        echo "$class_prefix" . " ." . $region . "-bgcolor-height-source-element {
            height: $height_value" . "px;
            height:" . (($height_value / $height_division) / 10) . "rem;
        }" . "   " . "

        $class_prefix" . " ." . $region . "-bgcolor-height  {
            top:" . "$height_value" . "px;
            top:" . (($height_value / $height_division) / 10) . "rem;
        } ";

    }


    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= css_height_output($region, $height_value, '', 1);


    if ($mobile_setting == '50%') {
        $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 959px) {" . css_height_output($region, $height_value, '.submenu-devices', 2) . "}";

        $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {" . css_height_output($region, $height_value, '.submenu-portables', 2) . "}";

        $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= css_height_output($region, $height_value, 'submenu-all', 2);


    } elseif ($mobile_setting == 'custom') {
        $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 959px) {" . css_height_output($region, $mobile_custom_height, '.submenu-devices', 2) . "}";

        $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {" . css_height_output($region, $mobile_custom_height, '.submenu-portables', 2) . "}";

        $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= css_height_output($region, $mobile_custom_height, '.submenu-all', 2);

    }

    echo $css_bgcolor_height_embeded;
}

echo css_bgcolor_height_embded('header', 10, 'custom', '100');

?>
```

Here is my output: (The code for the media query is wrongly placed outside of it [See end])

```
.header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 10px;
    height: 1rem;
}

.header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 10px;
    top: 1rem;
}

.submenu-devices .header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 100px;
    height: 5rem;
}

.submenu-devices .header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 100px;
    top: 5rem;
}

.submenu-portables .header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 100px;
    height: 5rem;
}

.submenu-portables .header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 100px;
    top: 5rem;
}

.submenu-all .header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 100px;
    height: 5rem;
}

.submenu-all .header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 100px;
    top: 5rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 959px) {
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
}
```

Here is what the output should be: (The code for the media query should be placed inside of it)

```
.header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 10px;
    height: 1rem;
}

.header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 10px;
    top: 1rem;
}


.submenu-all .header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 100px;
    height: 5rem;
}

.submenu-all .header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 100px;
    top: 5rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 959px) {

.submenu-devices .header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 100px;
    height: 5rem;
}

.submenu-devices .header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 100px;
    top: 5rem;
}

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .submenu-portables .header-bgcolor-height-source-element {
    height: 100px;
    height: 5rem;
}

.submenu-portables .header-bgcolor-height {
    top: 100px;
    top: 5rem;
}
}
```

(The final code will then be inserted into a Drupal function. However, I have left out the Drupal elements as I think this is more of a generic PHP problem).

Comment: Instead of `echo`ing your data in the functions, return it to a variable, and then echo the variable where appropriate. Unless I am misunderstanding your problem ^.^

Comment: @MattClark Post that as an answer.

Comment: `$var .= my_function(..);` in which `my_function(..)` returns a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insead of using `echo` in your `css_height_output` function, you should use return in its place. The problem is that `echo` will immediate output that string, instead of inserting it into the string where you are looking for it to be.

The ECHO function will at that point, take that text and output it to the body of the text, where as return will send that data back to what called it, in your case, adding it to the end of your `$css_bgcolor_height_embeded` variable.

```
function css_height_output($region, $height_value, $class_prefix, $height_division)
{
    return "$class_prefix" . " ." . $region . "-bgcolor-height-source-element {
        height: $height_value" . "px;
        height:" . (($height_value / $height_division) / 10) . "rem;
    }" . "   " . "

    $class_prefix" . " ." . $region . "-bgcolor-height  {
        top:" . "$height_value" . "px;
        top:" . (($height_value / $height_division) / 10) . "rem;
    } ";

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe that one little word caused me so much grief!

Comment: You would be surprised at how many letter case proBlems I have had... xD Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead...

```
<?php
function css_bgcolor_height_embded($region, $height_value, $mobile_setting, $mobile_custom_height)
{
    function css_height_output($region, $height_value, $class_prefix, $height_division)
    {
    return "$class_prefix" . " ." . $region . "-bgcolor-height-source-element {
        height: $height_value" . "px;
        height:" . (($height_value / $height_division) / 10) . "rem;
    }" . "   " . "

    $class_prefix" . " ." . $region . "-bgcolor-height  {
        top:" . "$height_value" . "px;
        top:" . (($height_value / $height_division) / 10) . "rem;
    }\n\n";

    }


    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded = css_height_output($region, $height_value, '', 1);


    if ($mobile_setting == '50%') {
    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 959px) {" . css_height_output($region, $height_value, '.submenu-devices', 2) . "}";

    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {" . css_height_output($region, $height_value, '.submenu-portables', 2) . "}";

    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= css_height_output($region, $height_value, 'submenu-all', 2);


    } elseif ($mobile_setting == 'custom') {
    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 959px) {" . css_height_output($region, $mobile_custom_height, '.submenu-devices', 2) . "}";

    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= "@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {" . css_height_output($region, $mobile_custom_height, '.submenu-portables', 2) . "}";

    $css_bgcolor_height_embeded .= css_height_output($region, $mobile_custom_height, '.submenu-all', 2);

    }

    return $css_bgcolor_height_embeded;
}

echo css_bgcolor_height_embded('header', 10, 'custom', '100');

?>
```

Pay attention to use return instead of echo. Echo prints it out at time of evaluation,

Comment: Thanks! Thanks also for the \n suggestion to make the output more readable.